# Insertar datos de una Consulta de postgresql a una tabla HTML

Tags: php, html, postgresql

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de realizar una tabla en HTML utilizando PHP para establecer la comunicación con la base de datos, el query es el siguiente

```
$query1="SELECT b.nombreforense, b.apelldoforense, COUNT(*) AS Total 
          FROM fallecido AS a 
    INNER JOIN forense AS b ON(a.forense_idforense = b.idforense) 
      GROUP BY b.nombreforense,b.apelldoforense ORDER BY Total";
```

El codigo utilizado en php es el siguiente:

```
<body>
    <?php
        if(!$records1)
        {    
        echo"Existe algun error. \n";
        exit;
        }

    echo "<table border=1px solid black>";
        echo "<th>Nombre y Apellido Forense </th><th>Casos Atendidos</th>";
        while ($row1=pg_fetch_array($records1))
        {   

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td align='center'>".$row1['nombreforense']." ".$row1['apelldoforense']."</td>"."<td>".$row1[Total]."</td>";
            echo"</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>


</body>
```

El problema radica en que si trae los datos de los atributos "nombreforense" y "apelldoforense" los datos de el total que se obtiene mediante el COUNT(*) no lo hace lo que muestra es lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito poder mostrar los casos atendidos y no se cual es el error o lo que falta en el codigo

Comment: debes usar el id SELECT b.nombreforense, b.apelldoforense, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM fallecido AS a INNER JOIN forense AS b ON(a.forense_idforense = b.idforense) GROUP BY b.id ORDER BY Total

Comment: Cambie el query pero sigue sin mostrarme el total de casos atendidos por forense

Comment: esa consulta no te devuelve nada en el pgadmin?

Comment: Si en el pgadmin si me cumple con lo que busco me muestra los datos de los forenses y sus casos atendidos

Comment: le faltan las comillas en `$row1['Total']`

Comment: haz un var_dump de $records1 y un count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo probaría a renombrar la columna Total, en minúsculas, tanto en la query como en el código PHP.

Postgresql no distingue mayúsculas y minúsculas en los nombres de columnas.

Answer (score 2):

En postgres, para que se reconozca el mayúsculas, tienes que ponerle comillas

```
SELECT b.nombreforense, b.apelldoforense, COUNT(*) AS "Total" 
FROM fallecido AS a 
INNER JOIN forense AS b ON(a.forense_idforense = b.idforense) 
GROUP BY b.nombreforense,b.apelldoforense ORDER BY Total
```

Sino, lo reconoce como total en minúsculas.

Osea **$row1['total']** debería funcionar.

En estos casos me gusta hacer un print_r($row1) para que el mismo PHP te renderice todo el objeto. Ahí vas a ver con que KEY te puedes referir al valor que buscas.

Rod

Comment: Correcto ROD! Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

le faltan las comillas en Total

```
echo "<td align='center'>".$row1['nombreforense']." ".$row1['apelldoforense']."</td>"."<td>".$row1['Total']."</td>";
```

Comment: Aun con las comillas no lo reconoce, ademas, en PHP las variables numéricas no necesitan las comillas simples solo las cadenas lo requieren

Comment: tu $row1 es a fin de cuentas un `map` que tiene un `key` y un `value`  en este caso el `key` es un `string` llamado 'Total';  sin importar el tipo del `value` deberias de poner las comillas.
revisa tu error_log y debe de estar lleno de: `Use of undefined constant total - assumed 'total'`

Comment: Ok pero te estoy comentando que al cambiar el total por 'total' aun mantiene la misma situación no arroja el valor del contador 'count(*)' del query

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoPedron lo que dices es muy difícil que suceda porque simplemente si la consulta te ha devuelto correctamente el total ésta **está disponible sí o sí en el array asociativo**. Por ende, `$row1['Total']` debería, forzozamente, devolver el valor que ha sido devuelto en la consulta.

Comment: Alternativamente, te recomiendo usar un template engine para mostrar los datos mucho más natural. Una opción es Blade. Mezclar lógica de negocio, y peor aún, de base de datos en vistas es una muy mala práctica que debes erradicar.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu consulta te genera los datos, entonces prueba con separar las columnas de tu tabla, osea algo asi...

```
echo "<td align='center'>".$row1['nombreforense']." ".$row1['apelldoforense']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$row1['Total']."</td>";
```

Puede que este asumiendo una misma cadena de caracteres en el echo y no te reconozca tus datos de la segunda columna, osea que todo el echo equivale a un solo .
Ademas sera un codigo mas entendible para cualquier programador que edite dicho codigo mas adelante

Saludos